# const char* const array

Tags: c++, arrays

I had a qestion, how can I update an array with more items, here let me show you what I mean.

```
const char* const Foo[] = {"Foo", "Bar"};
const char* const Bar[] = {"Bar", "Foo", "Foo Bar"};

Foo = Bar;
```

Basically updating "Foo" to "Bar"; How could I attempt this?

Comment: "How do I modify a `const`?" You can't. Even if you could, you need `std::vector`.

Comment: I presumed. How could I edit this array if you cant modify a "const"?

Comment: Why would you want to?  You have instructed the compiler that the pointer value itself cannot be modified.  It's part of your program's design, to prevent someone from accidentally violating some built-in requirement.  If you want to be able to modify it, then don't make it const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant, at lease like that. There are two reasons,

1. You cant assign an array to another array in C++.
2. What I understand by *Basically updating "Foo" to "Bar";* is you trying to add `{"Bar", "Foo", "Foo Bar"}` to `{"Foo", "Bar"}`. If so, you don't have the capacity in the `Foo` array.

What you need here is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This is a dynamically resizable array.

```cpp
#include <vector>    // For std::vector
#include <string>    // For std::string

std::vector<std::string> foo = { "Foo", "Bar" };
std::vector<std::string> bar = { "Bar", "Foo", "Foo Bar" };
```

But still you cannot just append elements from one array to another using the assignment (`=`) operator. You have to insert it.

```cpp
foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
```